# Want to add dates for week

Tags: php, date

I am using this code to `add a week` to a date:

```
$date1 = "2009-10-11";
$d = new DateTime($date1);
$d->modify( '+1 week' ); 
echo $d->format( 'Y m d' ), "\n";
```

It works fine good but want to add this functionality:

```
$startDate = "2009-10-11";
$endDate = "2010-01-20";
```

And want to create an array that holds ALL the +1 weeks IN BETWEEN these dates. How can i do this?

Comment: Are you saying that you want all the dates between 2009-10-18 and 2010-01-27, or is there some other interpretation?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
$startDate = "2009-10-11";
$endDate = "2010-01-20";

$dates = array();
$temp = strtotime($startDate);

do {
  $dates[] = date("Y-m-d", $temp);
  $temp = strtotime("+1 week", $temp);
} while ($temp < strtotime($endDate));

print_r($dates);
```

You can see a [demo here](http://3v4l.org/Ikk9T)

Comment: you could add this demo, if you wanted [http://3v4l.org/jQq4g](http://3v4l.org/jQq4g) ;)

Comment: Thanks @webeno. I have modified my answer to remove too many uses of strtotime(), and made a demo with modified answer.

Comment: @msound can you tell me how to do this if I have a SET number of dates I need between startDate and endDate instead of every week? Eg just 3 times, instead of every week?

Comment: @Alex Instead of "+1 week" just do "+23 days" or even "next Monday". Just look at the php documentation of [strtotime](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: @Alex If you want to divide the time interval by 3, I would suggest you look at [DateTime::diff](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) and divide the number of days by 3.

Answer (score 0):

Dates can be converted to timestamps. Timestamps are great for being compared because they basically just integers.

What I would do as a quick'n'dirty solution is to convert both your dates to timestamps and then design a loop like this (pseudo-code) :

```
timestamp = start_timestamp
WHILE timestamp < end_timestamp
    timestamp = timestamp + 1 week
    dates[] = timestamp
END WHILE
```

Comment: @nstCactus The problem with your pseudo-code is the last value in dates[] array will be after the end_timestamp. Hence my implementation uses `do ... while` instead of `while`.